# how to launchd on demand when port is specified as parameter?

Tags: mac-osx, launchd

I have a program I want to run on-demand using `launchd` by running the following command:

`/usr/local/bin/godoc -http=:6060`

This program starts an HTTP app that listens on the designated port 6060.

In my property list I have

```
<key>Sockets</key>
<dict>
    <key>default</key>
    <dict>
        <key>SockNodeName</key>
        <string>localhost</string>
        <key>SockServiceName</key>
        <integer>6060</integer>
        <key>SockPassive</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

However, when I start the daemon, the output from the application to stderr is:

`ListenAndServe :6060: listen tcp :6060: bind: address already in use`

From my understanding, `launchd` creates the socket and passes it to the app, but this app is trying to create the socket again so it fails.

What options do I have to run this with `launchd` on demand?

Comment: godoc doesn't support this. Just start it up at boot.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm surprised this isn't supported as it's so common for modern web apps

Comment: godoc isn't a modern web app, it's a simple tool to aid developers in working offline. You can also just start it up when you need it.